# Pass paramters to the report URL - ssrs report in power bi services

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssrs-2012

I have created a ssrs report with parameter and I deployed in power bi services.

Now i want to pass the parameter value in report url

I have tried the below syntax but it is not working

url?filter table/field eq 'value'

Comment: I think you need SSRS url filter parameter rather than PowerBI as your report is in SSRS.
Try something like below
`https://myspsite/subsite/_vti_bin/reportserver?https://myspsite/subsite/AdventureWorks 2008R2/Employee_Sales_Summary_2008R2.rdl&ReportMonth=3&ReportYear=2008`

Comment: Its working for me 


Parameter in URL 
Single parameter : url?rp:Parameter Name=value
Multiple parameter :url?rp:Parameter1 Name=value&rp:parameter2name=value
Note : Value have sapce in between use + sign